# No such file or directory PHP SLim

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I'm new in Slim framework and I have a problem about routing. Tried to follow the guide,but it still give me `no such file or directory` error. THis is my route

```
$app->get('/user/{email}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
    $email = $args["email"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=:email";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $response->withJson(["status" => "success", "data" => $result], 200);
});
```

This is how I call my route `localhost:8080/user/test@gmail.com`

And Have some more question, can we use two parameter and use it in query? This is the example `'user/{email}/{password}'` And call the url `localhost:8080/user/test@gmail.com/pass`. Usually I use NodeJs and use `req.params.email` and `req.params.password` to get the params, but i dont have any idea how to use it in PHP Slim. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the @ sign in a URL as a pseudo "parameter" is not recommended and can cause routing issues. To make it work better, you can use a classic query string instead.

```
GET example.com/user?email=test@gmail.com
```